# Bootstrap - open dropdown menu on top of modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My page structure is like this: a menubar, a content div and a footer. In the menubar, i have a dropdown, where the user has different links (profile, logout etc.) In the content div, in some places in the application I need to open a modal. But when the modal is opened, if I also click on the dropdown's arrow, it opens behind the modal, so the links are not clickable. z-index does not seem to help. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Bootstrap does not have menubars (do you mean navbar?) and modal dialogs are...modal, meaning you can't do anything to the page behind them; if you can interact with items on the page when the dialog is open, you're customizing things beyond the point of being able to reproduce it from description alone.

Comment: fiddle your code here, if possible

Comment: please share your fiddle or codepen for best solution.... either i think its only z-index issue.. use "position" with z-index value..